# Is there an Offset function in QGIS for Polygons?

Tags: qgis

IS there an offset function in qgis similar to that in autocad for polygons. I have an irregular shaped pollygon which i want to offset at 100m out from the edges, effectively adding 100m out each time.

I can do it buffering but does not show the exact shape.

Comment: Does this mean that you'd like to effectively increase the size of the polygon, without changing its shape? Around some central point?

Comment: I'm with - Simbamangu - the question isn't clear. An offset is where you move an item, so you'd offset it +100 on the X axis and the entire polygon would move 100m to the right. What you want to do is probably called something else (don't know what though).

Comment: I get what your saying, sadly I've not found this function it in QGIS, I'm sure that it'll come though. Its not the easiest thing to explain is offsetting. But imagine that you have two polygons or lines which are the same shape (a boundary for example).To show that two features occupy the same location in ArcMap (at least) you can offset one of the features so that you can see it side by side to the other feature. I've not found offsetting in QGIS yet but would either welcome it or would like to hear where its to be found.

Comment: It is called offset in Autocad was my point. Simbamangu had the jist of it. Med you were spot on.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your polygon shape to render offsetted, you could define the symbol with a Geometry Generator with the code :

```
offset_curve(   
line_merge(  exterior_ring(   force_polygon_ccw( $geometry)))
, 100)
```

where the "100" is your distance